# Regex - Look for Words in different Sentences

Tags: regex

In an original post by myself I asked for help working on a regular expression that solved inserting a keyword in a statement which was kindly answered, this  allowed me to resolve a powershell script of mine. I've since added to the expression however,

I'm looking for someone who can help fix a regular expression for me where I'm searching all the below sentences and appending a word to it.

- SELECT (NOLOCK)
- SELECT (INDEX=)
- SELECT (INDEX=,NOLOCK)

I have the regex expression to append a WITH between the SELECT and ( so it comes out like this:

- SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)

However it does not work for the following:

- SELECT (INDEX())
- SELECT (INDEX(),NOLOCK)
- SELECT isnull( SELECT  WITH (nolock) , NULL)

The expression is as follows:

```html
(?=\([^)]*(?=(NOLOCK|INDEX=|INDEX\()\b)[^())]*\))(?<!WITH\s+)
```

The issue is around the usage of word boundaries since ( is not in a word boundary.

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Kind Regards,

Paul.

Comment: Actually, [it works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%28%3f%3d%28NOLOCK%7cINDEX%3d%7cINDEX%5c%28%29%29%5b%5e%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=SELECT+%28INDEX%28%29%29%0d%0aSELECT+%28INDEX%28%29%2cNOLOCK%29&r=WITH+&o=i) with your last two strings.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, it would not work with SELECT isnull( SELECT WITH (nolock) , NULL), as it adds a WITH twice

Comment: Try `(?<!\bWITH)\s+(\((?:NOLOCK\b|INDEX\b=?))` pattern and replace with `" WITH $1"`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, that then removes characters including the words NOLOCK, example try using **SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (NOLOCK)**

Comment: It won't if you use the replacement I provided: `" WITH $1"`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cbWITH%29%5cs%2b%28%5c%28%28%3f%3aNOLOCK%5cb%7cINDEX%5cb%3d%3f%29%29&i=SELECT+*+FROM+dbo.Table+%28NOLOCK%29%0d%0a&r=+WITH+%241&o=i). Output for the string above is `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)`

Comment: Another regex that just adds `WITH` in between `.Table` and `(`+`NOLOCK` or `INDEX`: [`(\.Table)\s+(\((?:NOLOCK\b|INDEX\b=?))` -> `$1 WITH $2`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c.Table%29%5cs%2b%28%5c%28%28%3f%3aNOLOCK%5cb%7cINDEX%5cb%3d%3f%29%29&i=SELECT+*+FROM+dbo.Table+%28NOLOCK%29%0d%0a&r=%241+WITH+%242&o=i)

Comment: Thanks but the other expression was better at handling those scenarios however I just need to handle the ones that don't.

Comment: Do you realize you ask for a regex that will match balanced parentheses with a condition that some specific substrings should appear somewhere in it? Well, while it is possible, it will make the pattern even more incomprehensble.